# conditional test on ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am trying to check if a specific package is installed or not using Ansible. Here is my task

```yaml
    - name: check whether a package called {{ pkg_name }} is installed or not
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['pkg_name'] }} is installed"
      when: "pkg_name in ansible_facts.packages"
```

*pkg_name* is a variable defined by me, I've tried different combinations with *ansible_facts* like:

```yaml
    "{{ ansible_facts.packages['pkg_name'] }} is installed"
    "{{ ansible_facts.packages.{{ pkg_name }} }} is installed"
```

, but none of the methods works. However, if I simply put the string instead of the variable it works fine. For example,

```yaml
    ansible_facts.packages['httpd']
```

What is the correct syntax to check with the variable?
Also, confirm, can I pass an array to it to check multiple packages at the same time?

Comment: "but none of the method works" -- what happens? Are you getting an error message? What is it? Are you getting unexpected behavior?

Comment: yes its not accepting the syntax

Comment: Please update your question to include the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *pkg_name* is a variable. Do not quote it in the brackets

```yaml
  {{ ansible_facts.packages[pkg_name] }}
```

2. Do not quote the condition

```yaml
  when: pkg_name in ansible_facts.packages
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: foo

  tasks:

    - package_facts:
        manager: auto

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item].0.name }} is installed."
      when: item in ansible_facts.packages
      loop:
        - openssh
        - http
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [foo] ************************************************************************************

TASK [package_facts] **************************************************************************
ok: [foo]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [foo] => (item=openssh) => 
  msg: openssh is installed.
skipping: [foo] => (item=http) 

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
foo: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```